# Adicionar espaço após encontrar um caractere

Tags: delphi

Possuo o seguinte código que adiciona o conteúdo de um botão e um espaço após clicado

```
   procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
      begin
        if count = 0 then
          Edit1.Text := Edit1.Text + TLabel(Sender).caption+ ' ';

        if count = 1 then
          begin
            Edit2.Text := Edit2.Text + TLabel(Sender).caption+ ' ';
          end;
      end;

Saida: Dose = Max + Min
```

e uma outra situação para numero, que não aplica os espaços:

```
    procedure TForm3.Button29Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
         if count = 0 then
          Edit1.Text := Edit1.Text + TLabel(Sender).caption;

        if count = 1 then
          begin
            Edit2.Text := Edit2.Text + TLabel(Sender).caption;
          end;

    end;
Saida: Dose = 10
```

Porem estava pensando que após o numero poderia encontrar um texto
e do jeito que eu faria o caracter após o numero sairia assim

```
Saida: Dose = 10AND 20
```

Onde o correto seria:

```
Saida: Dose = 10 AND 20
```

Como tratar a função para que quando o próximo caracter após o numero seja um a letra, ele adicione um espaço?

Comment: você poderia sempre adicionar espaço, e no final da operação usar o trim() ?

Comment: Poderia até faço isso numa função, mas caso haja um AND após o numero, não iria adiantar nada.

Comment: quero dizer, tanto para numero quanto para texto, você adiciona espaço, no seu exemplo, você só adiciona para texto, ai no final, você usa o trim()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você poderia criar uma função nos seguintes moldes, onde SetOfChar é uma constante declarada:

```
SetOfChar = set of 'A'..'z';

function Concatena(const TextoEdit, Caption: String): String;
begin
  if TextoEdit = '' then
    Result := Caption
  else if TextoEdit in SetOfChar then
    Result := TextoEdit + ' ' + Caption
  else
    Result := TextoEdit + Caption;
end;
```